# New SIM card in Laos and Vietnam

Tags: cellphones, vietnam, laos, mobile-operators

How easy (in terms of procedure time, accessibility and cost) is it to get a new SIM in Laos and Vietnam? I'm traveling to Laos by air and Vietnam by land. Will I be able to get a SIM at Laos airport? Are they compatible with most mobile phones? Or, should I take international roaming on my native SIM (which is of an Indian operator) I'm asking about the compatibility because of an experience in Nepal.

Comment: "should" you is a matter of opinion. When i landed in ho chi minh city I got a prepaid tourist sim from the kiosk outside arrivals. $10 for unlimited high speed data. See also http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Prepaid_SIM_with_data

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing about your native SIM. Also have you done any own research? What constitutes "easy" for you? What is your mobile phone? Voting to close as unclear for now.

Comment: [This anecdote](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g293921-i8432-k6472552-SIM_card_Asia-Vietnam.html) suggests the process to buy a SIM in Vietnam is simple. However, without knowing how or where you're arriving into Vietnam, I don't know whether that helps you. [This thread](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/laos/laos-sim-card) suggests buying a SIM in Laos is straightforward and cheap. I assume that would beat your roaming rates, but I can't speak for them.